# dojo/cbtree: Checkboxes states for lazy loading mode

Tags: javascript, dojo

I initialize cbTree for lazy loading with FileStoreModel which has the parameter:
`checkedStrict: false`. As the data source use FileStore.
In my case, state of nested checkboxes don't affect to parental nodes. Likewise state of parental checkboxes don't affect to nested checkboxes.
If checkedStrict will have true value then cbTree will pull all nodes and leaves. This process may be very long.

How enable strict check for lazy loading mode without pulling all nested nodes?

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is unavailable for current implementation - described [here](https://github.com/pjekel/cbtree/issues/56)